# ParseFile Android C# Xamarin uploading/downloading images

Tags: c#, android, parse-platform, xamarin, imageview

I've successfully used Parse to upload and download sound clips to/from the device.
I'm trying a similar thing, but with images.
I have an imageView, which contains an image selected by the user.
I want to send this image as a parseFile nested inside a parseObject (called "profileParseObject")

I saw this post: [Putting image from gallery in ParseFile android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146665/putting-image-from-gallery-in-parsefile-android)

However,using:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.usman);
```

causes 'the name 'Bitmap' does not exist in the current context' (I don't know what assembly reference I need).

So the issue is: I Can't convert the data in the imageView into a byte[] to send it up to parse....
Also, if I was successful, how would I go about retrieving it back from parse then putting that data back into the imageView?

here's my attempt to upload, and thanks in advance for any help!

```
byte [] ImageData;
                    ImageData =  _imageView.ToArray<byte>();
                    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profilePic.png", ImageData);

                    profileParseObject["profilePicture"] = file;

                    if (canUpdate)
                    {
                        await profileParseObject.SaveAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully updated your information");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cannot update");
                    }
```

EDIT: I changed the code to use toArray(); this has compiled but I get the following error from the device:

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast from 'android/widget/ImageView'         to '[B'.
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.AssertCompatibleArrayTypes (IntPtr sourceArray, System.Type destType) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:744 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.GetArray[Byte] (IntPtr array_ptr) [0x00026] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:1207 
  at Java.Lang.Object.ToArray[Byte] () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.20-series/ba9bbbdd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:338 
  at PlugIt.Profile+d__7.MoveNext () [0x005ff]

Any ideas!?

Comment: ImageData =  _imageView.ToArray(byte); might do the trick !

Comment: Got an error, 'invalid expression term 'byte''

Comment: ToArray is a method and therefore you need to add the open and closed brackets.
`ImageData = _imageVIew.ToArray<byte>();

Comment: @arnfada Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't spot that!!!! Well, it compiles, but I can't test it at the moment as I don't have a device with me. Thanks a lot though, at least it builds :)

Comment: @CALBAGSHAW, I've added my comment as an answer. Please accept it if it fixes your error.

Comment: @arnfada Hi, although this compiled, when I ran it on the device I got an error. I've edited my original question with the new error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

ToArray is a method and therefore you need to add the open and closed brackets.

`ImageData = _imageVIew.ToArray<byte>();`

Edit:

The problem is that your'e trying to convert the imageView control into the byte array. What you need to do is to first fetch the image from the imageView and then convert that image into the byte array.

```
 //1. Get the Bitmap
BitmapDrawable drawable = imageView.GetDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.GetBitmap();

//2. Compress the bitmap into a stream and use that to get the byte array
byte[] imageData;
using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
    imageData = stream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Hi, although this compiled, when I ran it on the device I got an error. I've edited my original question with the new error, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this on the device and get back to you. Thankyou for your interest and help either way though! I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm missing the assembly reference to 'BitmapDrawable', what do I need? Thanks.

Comment: `Android.Graphics.Drawable.BitmapDrawable` or just add using `Android.Graphics.Drawable`